# How to inject raw Class to bean

Tags: java, spring

Let say I have such class:

```
public class MyClass {

  ...

  private Map<String, Class> eventsMapping = new HashMap<String, Class>();

  ...

}

public void setEventsMapping(Map<String, Class> mappings){
    this.eventsMapping = mappings;
}
```

How to create bean of such class with filled in eventsMapping? I mean XML definition of bean. The problem is that HashMap contains Classes and not objects.

I assume that it should be something like:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.my.MyClass" >
    <property name="eventsMapping">
        <map>
            <entry key="ABC">
               <bean class="java.lang.Class">
                   ???
               </bean>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

How to pass there particular Class (not an object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for your map to have `java.lang.Class` instances as values, then simply use

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.my.MyClass">
    <property name="eventsMapping">
        <map>
            <entry key="ABC" value="java.lang.Class" ></entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Spring will use a conversion service to change the `String` value `java.lang.Class` to a `Class` instance for `java.lang.Class`.

Similarly you can put the value in a `<value>` element.

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.my.MyClass">
    <property name="eventsMapping">
        <map>
            <entry key="ABC">
                <value>
                    java.lang.Class
                </value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="DEF">
                <value>
                    java.util.List
                </value>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot create** a bean of type `java.lang.Class` like this:

```
<bean name="aClassBean" class="java.lang.Class" />
```

**Reason:**

`From Javadocs:`

> Class has no public constructor. Instead Class  objects are constructed automatically by the Java Virtual Machine as classes are loaded and by calls to the defineClass method in the class loader.

To create a bean of type `java.lang.Class` create your beans like this:

```
<bean id="aClassBean" class="java.lang.Class" factory-method="forName">
      <constructor-arg value="full.package.name.of.the.class"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks! It is what I need however I will use Sotirios Delimanolis solution in this case

Comment: @ZginPrzepadnij: I believe both answers are little different. Did you end us using `factory-method="forName"` OR not?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using static factory method for bean creation:

```
<entry key="ABC">
     <bean class="java.lang.Class" factory-method="forName">
         <constructor-arg ref="className"/>
     </bean>
</entry>
```

You can also try using automatic conversion from fully qualified string to class but this may not work in you case when generic map is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
  <bean id="dbFieldConverters" class="java.util.HashMap">
      <constructor-arg>
         <map value-type="java.lang.Class">
             <entry key="tradeDate">
                <value>java.util.Date</value>
              </entry>
              <entry key="lastUpdate">
                  <value>java.sql.Timestamp</value>
               </entry>
          </map>
      </constructor-arg>
   </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

this works on my environment (Spring 4):

```
<map>
    <entry key="my-key">
       <value type="java.lang.Class">com.example.MyClassName</value>
    </entry>
</map>
```

Please note the target property is `Map<String, Class>` type and the `java.lang.Class` is used as value type attribute.